# Weird artifacts when making Buttons look like Spinners in API 21

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, material-design

I've got an app that I'm updating to a Material Design style, using the Android Support Library. Within the app, I have some elements that are actually `Button`s but are styled to look like `Spinner`s. When clicked, they pop up a date or time selector, and when a selection has been made the text updates.

The fragment of layout XML that creates these elements is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_date"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:hint="@string/hint_start_date"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_time"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/end_date"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:hint="@string/hint_end_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/end_time"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is unchanged from the previous version, where it worked fine. Since Lollipop, instead of rendering as I'd expect, a weird-shaped grey border appears (e.g. on a Nexus 6):

[image: What I see on the device]

When pressing and holding over the element, the base of the inner shape shrinks, so the grey triangles get wider.

I've tried overriding the style to use my own (slightly modified) copies of the original AppCompat Library drawables for the background. I've tried forcing the background to `@null`, and the artifacts are still there. The rendered preview in Android Studio shows a grey border on the left side of the elements which I also can't remove:

[image: Weirdness in Android Studio]

I genuinely have no idea where this is coming from. Any suggestions? Or perhaps thoughts on a different UI pattern to use?

- Test device: Nexus 6, Android 5.0
- Android studio version: 1.0.2
- Build tools version: 21.1.2
- AppCompat-v7 library version: 21.0.3
- Compile SDK version: 21
- Min SDK version: 15
- Target SDK version: 21

Comment: You can set android:stateListAnimator="null" or you can just use TextView. There's not really any reason to be using Button here.

Comment: Thanks @alanv – switching to TextView worked. I guess I just felt that Button was a closer match to the behavior I wanted.

I'd still be interested to know where those artifacts come from though; setting the stateListAnimator to null didn't make any difference.

Comment: The weird-shaped gray border artifacts are coming from shadows being rendered under what the framework thinks is opaque content. Removing the state list animator should remove the elevation / translationZ, which will remove the shadows.

Comment: I have the exact same artifact on the action bar, but only when using light theme! This is very annoying, digging into my theme didn't bring any particular differences between light/dark theme and it only happens on Android 5.0 since I integrated last support library, all previous versions of Android work just fine!